# How to mark a road as a toll road in Google Map Maker?

Tags: google-maps

If I tell Google Maps to avoid toll roads, it still takes me on a certain road which is in fact a **toll road**.

Does anyone know how I can edit the map to denote the road as such?

I see `road attributes` and `road priorities` on the `road details` page, but the **toll** option is not on there (did a search on both pages).

[image: "Add road details"]
[image: "Road attributes"]
[image: "Road priorities"]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this might be a case for the 'default' option. Click on Send Feedback (bottom right in desktop version) and then choose "Other Feedback".

Comment: Right-clicking the map on the road in question and choosing "Report a data problem" may be a better option.

Comment: Ah, okay. Not surprising they have multiple paths to the same thing.